# Unknown label type: 'continuous' sklearn LogisticRegression

Tags: python, logistic-regression, sklearn-pandas

I have the following code to test  ML algorithms of sklearn python library:

I got the following error in LogisticRegression call:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn import utils
y=np.array([ 2.664, 3.108, 7.104,  0.444, 1.776, 1.776, 1.776, 4.440])

x=np.array([[ 2.26414],
           [ 3.4893 ],
           [ 7.08023],
           [11.3826 ],
           [ 5.01367],
           [ 3.13454],
           [ 2.7636 ],
           [ 1.36057]])
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.2)

lr = LogisticRegression()
lr.fit(X_train, y_train)

lr.score(X_test, y_test)
ValueError  
----> 2 lr.fit(X_train, y_train)
ValueError: Unknown label type: 'continuous'
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: `LogisticRegression` expects `integer` values in `y`